# Mass editing DLINK Wireless router Virtual server list with browser?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

My IP address on LAN keeps changing, to 6, 5 or 8. Also, my outer doesn't have option to save IP address for specific MAC address.

Since I need to portforward my IP address.
So is there any way to mass edit the VIRTUAL sever list in router page ? Or where does it stores this info, anyway to debug and mass edit these entries?

[image: D-link router page virtual server list]

Comment: What is your router model? And your computer os?

Comment: Its Dlink DIR-600m wireless router. Im using Windows 8.1 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that router, but the fixing of IP addresses is done within the DHCP settings. If you can't find out how to do that, then you can set a fixed address in your PC. How you do it will depend on your OS, but it is pretty straightforward: it will required you to change the interface TCP/IP option from automatic to manual assignment.

Before you do this, check two things:

- make a note of the current settings which were automatically assigned - you will need to enter the same settings manually, apart from the interface IP address;
- check the DHCP settings in the router, so that you can choose a manual IP outside the range of the DHCP pool.

From your screen-shot it seems that the router assigns low-numbered IPs, so if you use something over 200 for the last field you should be well outside the automatic range: this is the only setting which should differ from those assigned automatically.

I use manually-assigned addresses, as I have found that fixing IP addresses in the router has often not worked properly. I also set the manually assigned addresses into the `hosts` files in my other machines on the network, for internal access without the overhead of a domain controller.

Comment: Yes I tried to set a fixed ip in my lan setting for my PC, it works. But as soon as some otehr user joins I loss my IP internet connection. Since his dynamic IP address 192.168.0.5 must be on his lease for unknown time.

Comment: yes thanks thats a good idea. I will set my IP to something 192.168.0.99

but only pain is going and adding all these entries again.